# Send Outlook Email with some Bold Text

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, format

I have code that opens up an Outlook email with the content of the mail body, but none of the format is working.

In the email, it just shows up as a string Like:

`<strong>Bold this part</strong>Unbold this text 
<b>This text bold</b>Test`

I have been searching answers here, but none of them work.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub Send_email()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim MailBody As String
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

MailBody = "First line of email" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "<strong>Bold this part</strong>" & "Unbold this text" & vbNewLine & _
           "<b>This text bold</b>" & "Test"

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Email Subject"
    .Body = MailBody
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `.HTMLBody` instead of `.Body`. For more, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MailItem.HTMLBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) instead of `MailItem.Body`.

> Returns or sets a String representing the **HTML** body of the specified item. Read/write.

```
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Email Subject"
    .HTMLBody = MailBody
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
```